# How to include first 5 table rows from MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I dont know if what i want is possible but i ask it anyway :)
I want to make a "news" container on my website. so if i add a new article than the oldest article must disappear. i thought, maybe it is possible to include only the first 5 rows of the database. And if that can be done then i have to insert the newest article on the first row of the database.

I hope that someone has a script that inserts a new article on the first row of my table AND a script that includes only the first 5 rows of my table.

Thanks
(sorry for my bad english by the way)

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM news
ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

to get the 5 latest news items.

---

As for inserting. Use a `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTOINCREMENT` to automatically get sequential id's for your news items.